# running selenium gives me connection refused errors

Tags: java, selenium

When I run selenium tests, I usually get a connection refused error after a while.

I run selenium server by doing:

```
java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--use-gl=osmesa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /home/jenkins-user/log/selenium.log &
```

and then run selenium tests.

Not all tests succeed because of connection refused errors. How do you help against connection refused errors? Is there a setting I can pass to selenium to help? Like browser timeout?